# java applet GUI with canvas

Tags: java, swing, applet

I want to make a ca concurrent applet. What I'm trying to do is to make kinda "customer-service" scenario. In that case a store has multiple waiting chairs and some staff dealing with customers in a given order. Here is an example pic of how I want it to look.

[image]

I've draw this in paint and ca how I'm looking for it will be. How can I code something like that? Just looking on the GUI regardless the canvas strings???

Comment: Have you tried a tutorial on applets and basic Java graphics?

Comment: Read up on [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: how often do you intend to ask the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444338/java-gui-drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout(2, 4)` and add `JPanel`s to it. Just use empty panels for the spaces and add a `Border` where you want the thick lines. You can add labels to the sub-panels later.